# Is there a way to make push notifications text wrap on Android devices codename one

Tags: android, push-notification, codenameone

I am developing a mobile app and when I send push notifications to the devices, Android devices do not seem to be able to wrap text like what on other applications do. Eg instead of displaying a string in 2 rows it just displays on one row and adds 3 dots at the end, however on IOS it works well. Is there something I can do to fix this.

Comment: Did you try push type 4 with title and second line or push type 1? Which Android OS version?

Comment: Hi Shai. I did try type 4 and 1 and still get the same results. I have tested this on the following Android OS versions : 4.4.2   , 5.1.1  and 8

Comment: We're looking into this, it's possible we can improve on it

Comment: I have added an RFE for this in the issue tracker.  https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2732

Comment: I see Steve Hannah closed this issue on github, does this mean it has been resolved and if so what do I need to do to get it working.